# Printable version in symfony

Tags: printing, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I use symfony 1.4 with Doctrine. How to make printable version of page in symfony?

I have module "company" and I want to make printable version of show action.

Is it possible to open information about my company in new window without sidebar, footer...content which I need to print?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// company/config/view.yml

showSuccess:
  has_layout: false
```

'The view.yml configuration file defines the default layout used by the application. By default, the name is layout, and so symfony decorates every page with the layout.php file, found in the application templates/ directory. You can also disable the decoration process altogether by setting the ~has_layout~ entry to false' (c. [The view.yml Configuration File](http://www.symfony-project.org/reference/1_4/en/13-View) ).